# SQL SUM condition on each column

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm giving my best efforts to write a query to get the desired output format shown the second table here. Is there a better way to achieve this, table 1 has the raw data and I want to find the sum of monthly usage of unique devices for a given user. Any help is really appreciated.

[table format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOCNe.png)

Apologize for not being clear in first place. tagged different image to illustrate better. If you look at this data in new image attached. After I filter by username - I get that data output. My need is to get the sum of usage by month by device.

Ex: rows highlighted in the image, where iPhone-6sPlus is used multiple times each month across months. I'm looking for a query that gives output as 
iPhone-6SPlus is used xx_hrs in Jan, yy_hrs in feb so on. Similarly for other device models. Hope this helps. Thanks.

[Better image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOP8S.png)

Comment: You need to show us more information than a couple of sentences and a hard to read table image.

Comment: Search for pivot table. Add in your question your attempt, at least we know that you really tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create table #product (model varchar(50),users varchar(5), monthofuse Varchar(3),yearofuse int,usage int)

Insert into #product values('X','a', 'JAN',2010,34),    ('X','a', 'Feb',2010,20),('X','a', 'Mar',2010,10),('Y','a', 'Jan',2010,30),
('Y','b', 'Jan',2010,30),('Y','b', 'Feb',2010,30),('X','a', 'JAN',2011,50)

select * from #product

Select * FROM
(Select users,monthofuse,usage,model from #product) q
Pivot 
(
sum(usage) for q.monthofuse in([JAN],[FEB],[MAR],[APR],[MAY],[JUN],[JUL],[AUG],[SEP],[OCT],[NOV],[DEC]))As pvttable
```